# how to search for a value in different Json files

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

what i trying to do is when a user enters the longtitude and latitude of a location, the application returns the associated grid code which is stored in one of the 3 json data files.
i am trying to search in all three files at the same time this is my try but smees  not working.

```
  async function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long){
    const response=await fetch('data/GHI_part01.json');
    const line=await response.json();

    var result = line.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long);
       if (result) {
      return result.GRIDCODE;
       } else {
      lookupGHI_part02(lat, long);
       }

}
async function lookupGHI_part02(lat, long){
    const response=await fetch('data/GHI_part02.json');
    const line=await response.json();
    var result = line.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long);
       if (result) {
      return result.GRIDCODE;
       } else {
      lookupGHI_part03(lat, long);
       }
}
async function lookupGHI_part03(lat, long){
    const response=await fetch('data/GHI_part03.json');
    const line=await response.json();

    var result = line.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long);
       if (result) {
      return result.GRIDCODE;
       } else {
      return new Error('No records found');
       }
}
$("#Btn" ).click(function() {
    lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long)
    .then(gridcode => {
    var ghi = gridcode;})
$("#result").show();
$("#resultat").html(ghi);
}
```

this how my data look like

```
[{"GRIDCODE":2115,"Lat":29.478,"Long":-5.565},{"GRIDCODE":2115,"Lat":29.478,"Long":-5.562},{"GRIDCODE":2115,"Lat":29.486,"Long":-5.572},{"GRIDCODE":2113,"Lat":29.483,"Long":-5.567},{"GRIDCODE":2109,"Lat":29.483,"Long":-5.559},{"GRIDCODE":2115,"Lat":29.485,"Long":-5.554},{"GRIDCODE":2115,"Lat":29.493,"Long":-5.616},{"GRIDCODE":2120,"Lat":29.492,"Long":-5.609},{"GRIDCODE":2116,"Lat":29.492,"Long":-5.601},{"GRIDCODE":2116,"Lat":29.492,"Long":-5.592},{"GRIDCODE":2115,"Lat":29.493,"Long":-5.584},{"GRIDCODE":2110,"Lat":29.491,"Long":-5.575}]
```

Comment: what is not working exactly?  how large are these files, and do you need to search them more than once?

Comment: the files contain more than 100000 line and yes the search should be more than once and also i can't use all of the as one file (conaint about 500000 line)  it cause a violation load on the browser so that's why i separated them into 3 sub files

Comment: still need to clarify what your problem is.  I can't really test it to see what is happening. 
 are you running into issues with the browser locking up due to overly large data, or is it just not functioning?

Comment: the problem is i have 3 json files so when the user enter the longtitude and latitude the app should return the gridcode associted them which is located in one of these 3 files i tryed the code obve but it return nothing i can't  demostrate cuz the amount of data in the 3 files

Comment: You might look into doing this search on the back end. or, at the very least, load the 3 JSON files as variables at the very beginning so you only have to do it once

Comment: @Alchemist you could show us an example of the data from each of the 3 files, that'd help a lot, not the whole files, just a couple rows from each

Comment: @WesleySmith check now please

Comment: Try changing your code to `var result = line.find(x => x.Lat == lat && x.Long == long);` using capital "L"s in `x.Lat` and `x.Long`

Comment: @WesleySmith thanks bro did'nt pay attention

Comment: @WesleySmith but the main problem is how to search in 3 json files at same time the method i tried is to combine 3 function but it returns undefined

Answer (score -1):

first error was in

```
var result = line.find(x => x.Lat == lat && x.Long == long);
```

I changed to capital "L"s in `x.Lat` and `x.Long`

scecond inseted of calling function inside another funcution i change it to this

```
    async function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long){
    const response=await fetch('data/GHI_part01.json');
    const line=await response.json();
    var check =0;
    var result = line.find(x => x.Lat == lat && x.Long == long);
       if (result) {
      return result.GRIDCODE;
       }
             else {
       var check = 1;
       }
             if (check == 1)
             {
                const response=await fetch('data/GHI_part02.json');
                const line=await response.json();

                var result = line.find(x => x.Lat == lat && x.Long == long);
                   if (result) {
                  return result.GRIDCODE;
                   } else {
                    check = 2
                   }
             }
             if (check = 2)
             {
                 const response=await fetch('data/GHI_part03.json');
                const line=await response.json();

                var result = line.find(x => x.Lat == lat && x.Long == long);
                   if (result) {
                  return result.GRIDCODE;
                   } else {
                  return new Error('No records found');
                   }
             }
}
```